Issue in accessing the jwt token in api gateway designed using springboot
I have designed a api gateway using spring cloud gateway which accepts request and will verify the user by obtaining the jwt token from request header if the user is valid then it will route the request to the requested url.
and we are using keycloak and ldap for token generation
I have not tried it because not able to find any solution for the same.

Hey, friendly reminder: This Page doesn't exist to do the work for you, but to help solve the problems you stumble upon trying it yourself. So rather than saying 'I have not tried it because not able to find any solution', you should start trying and when you come across a specific, reproducible Problem, then this Community can help you.
Here is a Guide for Better Questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You will have to write config file in which you will write jwt filter through which you will be checking for jwt valid or not. then you can do this

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String authorizationHeader = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {

            String jwtToken = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
         }

this is how you can get it.
